# Can't dispatch click on valid selector using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs

Using Casperjs,  I'm trying to dispatch a click event to one of the links on a page. It's position is dependent on the size of the window so multiple instances of it exist. For this reason I'm using a selector based on its parent. I don't dispatch the even till it's confirmed to not equal `undefined` and I was previously checking against `null`. When I print objects matching the selector I'm using I get `[object Object]`, but when I try to dispatch the click event I receive an error stating `"Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector"`. How is this possible if `querySelectorAll()` returns objects for the same selector. This is the code I'm using.`

```
casper.each(links, function() {
this.waitFor(function check() {
    return (this.evaluate(getSelector,'div.talk-hero__tools__list__actions a.rate-button') != undefined);
    },
    function then() {
        this.echo(this.evaluate(getSelector,'div.talk-hero__tools__list__actions a.rate-button'));
        this.click('div.talk-hero__tools__list__actions a.rate-button');
});
});
```

Comment: Why didn't you use `waitForSelector`?

Comment: I hadn't realized that existed. However when I tried it I saw the same results as when I followed the advice below.

Comment: You try to automate TED, right? Strange thing is that I don't have such an error using `waitForSelector` and `click`, but also nothing happens on the page. I'm using Phantom 1.9.7 with casper 1.1.0-beta3.

Comment: Indeed I am, very perceptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that `casper.each()` doesn't open the link. I solved it by adding a `casper.thenOpen()` around all the code in the `each()`.

Comment: You know, this answer doesn't make sense for this question as it doesn't say anything about `each` or `open`. Maybe you should edit your question (by adding a part of your script) to match your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (adding an anonymous function to your call to `evaluate`, and switch selector check from `undefined` to `null`):

```
this.waitFor(function check() {
  return this.evaluate(function() {
    return document.querySelector('div.talk-hero__tools__list__actions a.rate-button') !== null;
  });
}, function then() {
    this.echo(this.evaluate(getSelector,'div.talk-hero__tools__list__actions a.rate-button'));
    this.click('div.talk-hero__tools__list__actions a.rate-button');
});
```

Comment: I tried this, it timed out. How is this possible if queries for that selector were previously returning values.